# _.indexOf doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have the following code snippet:

```
const summerIndex = _.indexOf(model.xAxis, monthLabel);
```

When I debug the code, `model.xAxis` contains

```
Array[12]

0 :"Mar 2016"
1 : "Apr"
2 : "May"
3 : "June"
4 : "July"
5 : "Aug"
6 : "Sept"
7 : "Oct"
8 : "Nov"
9 : "Dec"
10 : "Jan 2017"
11 : "Feb"
length:  12
__proto__:  Array[0]
```

and `monthLabel` is `0`.

But the value of `summerIndex` after passing this step is `-1`. Is this the normal behavior in this case?

Comment: Yes. `-1` means value not found. Since there is no value `0` it will return `-1`. If you are assuming the return value to be "May 2016", try `model.xAxisLabels[monthLabel]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Mar 2016`?

Comment: I'll try to explain. `indexOf` will look for passed value with **value** of every item and would return matched value's index. Since you do not have any value as `0` it will return `-1`. Since you have index value, you can directly access value at a given index as `array[index]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has misunderstood a feature and hence was expecting incorrect output.